# Display featured images from light to dark in grid view of wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, image, display

I'm working on a task where I need to display a featured images of my custom post type (products) in a grid view (https://www.screencast.com/t/qH51G0Sv) on the front end page template from light to dark like hue formula. I didn't get any luck to find a WordPress plugin/script or best solution on the google. The Stackoverflow is my last hope :( Please help me here.

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is , at first try o add a meta box to set dark value into that custom post type. Then write wp meta query for that.

Comment: Thanks, Souvik Sikdar. I'm trying to read those hue values from the post "featured image" at a time of uploading it or saving a post. Is it possible?